# Number of colors for symmetric colored grid with monochromatic diagonal

Tags: matrices, solution-verification, latin-square

I consider a finite quadratic grid with side length $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Every square in the grid will be colored, such that every color appears at most once in any row or column. Additionally, all diagonal elements have the same color and I impose the condition that the coloring of the grid is symmetric with respect to diagonal when represented as a matrix. How many colors, additionally to the color of diagonal, do I need at least to color the square?

Using some examples, I came to the conclusion that for $n$ odd, I need $n$ colors and for $n$ even I need $n-1$.
For the proof, I define $\chi(n)$ as said number and I use that there are $\binom{n}{2}$ fields in the upper triangle and the first line has to contain $n-1$ different colors. Additionally, all colors have to appear with the same frequency $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$ in the whole square, such that $n(n-1)=\alpha\chi(n)$. Note that $\alpha$ has to be even, since all colors appear the as many times below the diagonal as they do above.
Now, if $n$ is even, then for $\alpha = n$ we obtain $\chi(n)=n-1$ and this gives a viable coloring of the square. Now assume that for $n$ odd, we also have $\chi(n)=n-1$. Then $\alpha = n$ also in this case, but this is a contradiction to $\alpha$ being even and the next larger possibility $\chi(n)=n$ gives $\alpha=n-1$ and, therefore, a viable coloring.

Is this correct or did I miss something? Maybe it can be done in a more elegant way.

Comment: When you say "symmetric", do you mean as a matrix? I.e. reflection symmetry across the main diagonal?

Comment: Yes, exactly, in matrix representation.

Comment: What do you mean by colors?  I've seen latin squares, but an $n\times n$ square filled with numbers is usually only a latin square if $n$ distinct numbers are used. Is there some variation where we can use more than $n$ numbers and still call it a latin square?

Comment: So can you tell us what a latin square is, since you are obviously not using the standard definition, such as at Wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square

Comment: OK, sorry, that is true,... I simply wanted to color a qudratic finite grid symmetrically around the diagonal and the diagonal being colored in one fixed color.

Comment: But you also want the frequencies of each color (other than the diagonal color) to be the same? Do you want the columns and rows to have distinct colors, like a latin square, or is any coloring allowed? Please. update your question to clarify what you mean. I'd start by editing out references to latin squares, or at least calling it a variant.

Comment: I made some changes which, hopefully, clear it up.